# replace all "foo" between ()

Tags: php, regex

I've problem with my regex code, the problem is: I want to replace all "foo" values but only inside "()". Example:

```
try foo foo-foo (try foo inside , foo foo foofoo)
```

I want to replace all "foo" strings between the parentheses by "boo".

Comment: Where's your regex code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming parentheses are "valid", you can replace all `foo`s that are followed by `)`, without a `(` in between:

```
$str = preg_replace('/foo(?=[^()]*\))/', 'bar', $str);
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/xezU7

Another option, also assuming no nested pairs, is to match `"(...)"` tokens and use a callback, but it may be use of excessive force:

Callback method:

```
function replace_foo($matches) {
   return str_replace('foo', 'bar', $matches[0]);
}
```

use:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback("/\([^()]*\)/","replace_foo", $str);
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/ZzBem

Comment: Thats a very specific but clever solution :) My answer includes a more general solution :)

Comment: What's with `foo) (foo)`? The first foo would also be replaced, but it's not inside `()`.

Comment: @levu - There's an underlying assumption that the parentheses are properly matched and aren't nested. Otherwise, it's up to the OP to handle the eccentric edge cases.

Comment: +1 for the callback solution. And to allow for nested `(foo(foo)foo)`, change the callback regex to: `'/\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)/'`. :)

Answer (score 1):

This finds all occurences of `foo` inside `()` and replace them with `str_replace`. From my experience I can say, that this is faster than `preg_replace`.

```
while (preg_match_all('/^(.*)(\([^\)]*foo[^\)]*\))(.*)$/', $string, $pat)) {
    $string = $pat[1] . str_replace('foo', 'boo', $pat[2]) . $pat[3];
}
```

Note the three groups: The string before the `(` (`$pat[1]`), the string in the `()` which contains `foo` (`$pat[2]`) and the string behind the `)` (`$pat[3]`).

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with using a loop and replacing multiple times, this solution will work:

```
do {
  $string = preg_replace('/(\([^)]*)foo([^)]*\))/U', '\1boo\2', $string, -1, $count);
}while($count != 0);
echo $string;
```