# PHP : replace all "foo" string between "style='()'" using regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace all “foo” between ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755936/replace-all-foo-between)

Hello,

I tried to use regex to replace all `foo` string between the `()` which between `style=" and "`

Here's an example :

```
blah blah foo blah style="foo text blah (foo and blah foo)"
```

it should be replaced to be :

```
blah blah foo blah style="foo text blah (bar and blah bar)"
```

i tried to use this code but it dont working .

```
do {
  $code = preg_replace('/(style\=\"[^)]*)left(?=[^()]*\))([^)]*\")/U', '\1tempvalue\3', $code, -1, $count);
} while($count != 0);
```

then im trying to using foreach to get the results,, then replace it normally using preg_replace .

i wish to find the answer :) ,, thank you.

Comment: not a Good practice ;btw do u need thid : http://rubular.com/r/uivdGaQkoJ

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` to find the `style=".*?"` and then a second regex to adapt the search text in parenthesis.

Comment: Oh, looks like you got that recommendation before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755936/replace-all-foo-between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on your string, might need modifying a bit to work in all circumstances...

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/style="(.*)(\(.+\))"/',create_function(
   '$matches',
    'return "style=\"" . $matches[1] . preg_replace("/foo/","bar",$matches[2]) . "\"";'
),'blah blah foo blah style="foo text blah (foo and blah foo)"');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
/style=".*?\((.*?)\)"/
```

Explanation:

- **`style=`"** matches the same thing
- **`.*?`** match any character but not in a greedy way, just as minimum as possible
- **`\(`** matches (
- **`(.*?)`** match any character between the style and parentheses, meaning this is the information you should replace
- **`\)"`** matches )"

You can use [THIS](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) tool to build regex strings. It's really helpful, it has some examples and it will tell you what part matches which string.

Answer (score 0):

A working regex is:

```
style="[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)"
```

But since you will have more than one matches (0 for the whole, 1 for the values in parenthesis), you will have to use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good use of `PREG_REPLACE_EVAL` [(e modifier)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$str = 'blah blah foo blah style="foo text blah (foo and fooblah foo)" foo';
echo preg_replace('~(style="[^(]*)(\([^)]*\))~ie', "str_replace('\\\\\', '', '$1') . preg_replace('#\bfoo\b#i', 'bar', '$2')", $str) ."\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
blah blah foo blah style="foo text blah (bar and fooblah bar)" foo
```