# How to replace all specific strings between specific strings?

Tags: php, regex

I like to replace all `\n` inside of `<pre></pre>` with a placeholder. This is what I created:

```
<?php
$html = "<div>\n<pre id=foo>Foo\n\nBar Bar\nFoo Foo</pre>\n\n</div>";
echo preg_replace("/(<pre[^>]*>[^<]*)(\n)([^<]*<\/pre)/", "$1{NEWLINE}$3", $html);
?>
```

It replaces only one `\n` as expected. Do I need to use preg_replace_callback() and a separate function to replace the linebreaks or is it possible with one regex alone?

EDIT: Any solution available for this, too?

```
$html2 = "<div>\n<pre id=foo><b>Foo\n\n</b>Bar Bar\nFoo Foo</pre>\n\n</div>";
```

Comment: @hwnd good point. I should replace `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\n` and `\r` by `{NEWLINE}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is duplicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756032/318765

This is what I need:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("/(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)(?=[^<>]*<\/pre)/", "{NEWLINE}", $html);
?>
```

Comment: If you're looking for a single call, I would suggest `preg_replace('~\R+(?=[^<]*</pre>)~', '{NEWLINE}', $html);`

Comment: Thanks. This is not part of the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.escape.php) but it works.

Comment: I added $html2. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: You find $html2 in my question. It has a nested `<b>` and this will break the single call.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a callback as you suggested.

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('~<pre[^>]*>\K.*?(?=</pre>)~si', 
     function($m) {
        return str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '{NEWLINE}', $m[0]);
     }, $html);
```

Although, I would recommend using [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to perform this task.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('pre');
$find  = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   $node->nodeValue = str_replace($find, '{NEWLINE}', $node->nodeValue);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Please pay attention to $html2. It has a nested `<b>`.

Comment: `\K` is nice to now. This is for better performance, correct?